# How to set Maximum PageSize per Page in gridView in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net

I want to set Maximum Pagesize per Page in gridview.If you know ,please tell me.

Answer (score 3):

From MSDN we see that the PageSize is Integer. So the maximum is the `int.MaxValue`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.pagesize.aspx

but it will be better just to set `AllowPaging="false"`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.allowpaging.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Use the PageSize property to specify the maximum number of records **per page**. The default page size is 10, below I have changed this to 100. If you have 250 records in your DataSource your gridview will have 3 pages with 100 on the first 2 pages.

```
<asp:GridView id="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="100"
DataSourceID="SQLdbSrc">
```

Follow the first link @Aristos provided to see this property explained in full.

Answer (score 1):

I see @Aristos got few upvotes and did not get correct answer because code snippet was incorrect.
Should update to:

```
YourGridviewID.AllowPaging=false;
```

Comment: @PetterFriberg See the review link https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/16623734 This came up in the Low Quality Posts review list. Right now you are 50/50 on votes. I was just the first to leave a comment. Aristos answer is essentially correct, just more generic. Your answer, IMO,  should really have been a comment to his. And I realize you don't yet have the reputation to comment, but that's just the way SO works.